# Expectation and $L^p$ space (subgaussian random variable)

Tags: probability-theory, lp-spaces, expected-value, gaussian

I've come across the following statement (unfortunately w/o proof, or any details). The statement is as follows:

> **Lemma.** Let $X$ be a random variable, and recall that the common definition of a subgaussian random variable. That is, if there exists a finite $c$ such that the moment generating function $\mathbb{E}\left[\exp\left(c^{-1}X^2\right)\right] < \infty$, then we say $X$ is subgaussian. Equivalently, $X$ is subgaussian when $\sup_{1 \leq p < \infty}p^{-1/2}||X||_p < \infty.$

So rewriting, I would like to prove that:

$$\exists c < \infty~\text{such that}~\mathbb{E}\left[\exp\left(c^{-1}X^2\right)\right] < \infty \quad\Leftrightarrow\quad \sup_{1 \leq p < \infty}p^{-1/2}||X||_p < \infty.$$

**So far.**

$\Leftarrow$: Since $X$ is a random variable we have that

$$\sup_{1 \leq p < \infty}p^{-1/2}||X||_p = \sup_{1 \leq p < \infty}p^{-1/2}\left(\mathbb{E}|X|^p\right)^{1/p} < \infty.$$

Not exactly sure how to proceed from here, but the idea I believe is to get the following

$$\sup_{1 \leq p < \infty} p^{-1/2}\left(\mathbb{E}|X|^p\right)^{1/p} = \sup_{1 \leq p < \infty}  \int |x|^pd\mu = \dots = \int_0^{\infty} P\left[\exp\left(c^{-1}X^2 \geq x \right)\right]dx = \mathbb{E}\left[\exp\left(c^{-1}X^2\right)\right].$$

$\Rightarrow:$ Not quite sure, but I think we could invoke something like Markov's inequality to start. But I'm not really seeing it.

Comment: $\impliedby$ follows by series expansion of the exponential.